# Java project - mariadb syntax error when i try to create a procedure

Tags: java, mysql, maven, mariadb

I am developing a script in Java with which I manipulate files and execute queries on the DB, in particular I use MariaDB.
In the script I need to create a procedure, called `NP_update_collection_state`.

But when I run the script the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter ;; CREATE PROCEDURE ....`

Do you have any suggestions or advice? It is the first time that this error has occurred to me and I cannot understand the problem.
Reading about problems here on stack I noticed that the problem could come from `delimiter`, I tried to remove it but I always get syntax error.

- My procedure:

```
String sqlCreaNP =  "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `NP_aggiorna_stato_riscossione`; "+
 "delimiter ;; "+
 "CREATE PROCEDURE `NP_aggiorna_stato_riscossione`() "+
 "BEGIN "+
 " "+
 " "+
   "DECLARE finito INTEGER DEFAULT 0; "+
   "DECLARE M_saldato INTEGER DEFAULT NULL ;"+
   "DECLARE M_parametroDiTolleranza decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 3; "+
   "DECLARE contatore INT DEFAULT 0; "+
   "DECLARE righeTrovate INT DEFAULT 0; "+
   "DECLARE W_eseguito INT DEFAULT 0; "+
   " "+
    "DECLARE W_idDoc bigint(13) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL; "+
    "DECLARE W_docImporto decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0; "+
    "DECLARE W_versato decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0; "+
    "DECLARE W_ancoraDaVersare decimal(11,2) DEFAULT 0; "+
    " "+
    " "+
    "DEClARE CF_cursor CURSOR FOR "+
        "SELECT tbl_versamenti_f24.idDoc, tbl_documento.docImporto, sum(importoDebito), (tbl_documento.docImporto - sum(importoDebito)-tbl_statoriscossione.docVersato) "+
        "FROM tbl_versamenti_f24 INNER join tbl_documento on tbl_versamenti_f24.idDoc=tbl_documento.idDoc "+
        "inner join tbl_statoriscossione on tbl_statoriscossione.idDoc=tbl_versamenti_f24.idDoc "+
        "where tbl_versamenti_f24.idDoc is not null "+
        "group by tbl_versamenti_f24.idDoc "+
        "order by 4; "+
        " "+   
        " "+
    "DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER "+ 
    "FOR NOT FOUND SET finito = 1; "+
    " "+  
    " "+
    "SELECT ' ' as '*** Inizio riconciliazione ***', curdate() as 'data iniziale', curtime() as 'ora iniziale'; "+
    "INSERT INTO tbl_splog (marcatura,evento,valore) values (current_timestamp(),'Inizio riconciliazione','NP'); "+
" "+
" "+
    "SELECT eseguito into W_eseguito from tbl_controllo where evento = 'NP_aggiorna_stato_riscossione'; "+
    " "+
    " "+
        "update tbl_statoriscossione "+
            "set docPagato = 1 "+
            "where docImporto <=0; "+
 " "+
    "OPEN CF_cursor; "+
    "set righeTrovate = FOUND_ROWS(); "+
    "select righeTrovate; "+
 " "+
 " "+
 "get_dati: LOOP "+
    "FETCH CF_cursor INTO W_idDoc,W_docImporto,W_versato,W_ancoraDaVersare; "+
    "IF finito THEN "+ 
        "LEAVE get_dati; "+
    "END IF; "+
    " "+
        "set M_saldato = 0; "+
        "if (M_parametroDiTolleranza > W_ancoraDaVersare)  "+
        "then "+
            "set M_saldato = 1; "+
        "end if; "+
        "UPDATE tbl_statoriscossione "+
        "SET docVersato = W_versato, quantoManca = W_ancoraDaVersare, docPagato = M_saldato "+
        "where idDoc = W_idDoc; "+
 " "+
 "END LOOP get_dati; "+ 
 " "+
 "CLOSE CF_cursor; "+
 " "+
 " "+
 " "+
 " "+
 " "+
   " -- update tbl_rata A join tbl_versamento_new S on S.idBol = A.idBol "+
   " -- set A.pagato = 1; "+
" "+
" "+     
" "+ 
" "+ 
 "END "+
 ";; "+
 "delimiter ;";
```

Comment: DELIMITER is client command, not SQL statement. You must reassign the delimiter in the method which will execute your multiquery.

Comment: Try running the drop and create in separate db calls, and don’t set the delimiter.

Comment: @Akina i've this method `createProcedureStatoRiscossione(c, sqlCreaNP);`, in this method i need to reassign delimiter?

Comment: This method is a method in your program. I tell about the method which sends the SQL query text to MySQL server.

Comment: @Bohemian, i've tried to split into two db calls, the first one i'ts ok, but the second one ( the create procedure ) returns the following mysql error ` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1` and i don't know why